# From javascript external file cannot get id from HTML file and replace content

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>Design All</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <h2>------------------------</h2>
        <h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>
        <h2>------------------------</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

External JavaScript Code:

```
var product = "Camera";
var price = 130;
var introduction = document.getElementById("test");
introduction.innerHTML = product + " " + price;
```

Note: 
1. If i use a function call, it works.
2. If i write the script within the HTML file, it works as well.
3. I used jsfiddle, it displays perfectly fine.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you make sure the document is loaded before continuing?

Comment: Your javascript is loaded and executed, before the body is loaded aka the DOM is not ready yet. Use a library like jQuery which offers callbacks for events like DOMready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you have to be clear is that HTML loaded sequentially.
In your code

```
...........................
<script src="index.js"></script>
................
.................... 
 <h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>
```

Here the JavaScript loaded first then the remaining html.
As the JavScript will execute when it is loaded for the way you write it, it will not find the later html tags. So it will not get that element (`<h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>`).

But if you load the JS later then it will work as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Design All</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h2>------------------------</h2>
    <h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>
    <h2>------------------------</h2>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

That's why experts suggest to load JS at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think HTML was not loaded yet. Use onload attribute on body to ensure DOM is loaded :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    var myFunction = function() {
      var product = "Camera";
      var price = 130;
      var introduction = document.getElementById("test");
      introduction.innerHTML = product + " " + price;
    }
    </script>
    <title>Design All</title>
    </head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <h2>------------------------</h2>
    <h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>
    <h2>------------------------</h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Design All</title>
         <script src="index.js"></script>        
</head>
    <body onload = "chng()">
        <h2>------------------------</h2>
        <h1 id="test">Should this change?!</h1>
        <h2>------------------------</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
// JavaScript
function chng(){
var product = "Camera";
var price = 130;
var introduction = document.getElementById("test");
introduction.innerHTML = product + " " + price;
}
```